# Git Stash Pop Merge Conflict Resolution and Reason

Tags: git, git-pull, git-stash

I've recently been using `git stash`, `git pull`, and `git stash pop`  as my work flow when I need to sync up to what other devs are doing, but save what I'm working on first, and then continue working. I recently did a `git pull` to get everything new and it worked with no problem, I was caught up. A few hours later I did stash/pull/pop and and got a merge conflict when doing the `git pop`. I saw that the conflicts were between code I recognized I had written a long time ago and what I was trying to currently pull from just a couple hours in between the clean pull and this one.

Could this be because I didn't clear my stash after I resolved a merge conflict from the past, therefore any subsequent pop + conflict tries to use the most recent stash where a conflict also occurred?

I guess what I'm saying is, if you get a conflict and resolve it after popping your stash, do you need to manually remove that stash to avoid this next time you pop with conflict? I thought stash pop was supposed to remove the stash, but I take it it doesn't if there's a conflict... so it needs to be done manually to avoid the unexpected situation where it was trying to get me to resolve conflicts between the recent pull I did and code that was done and pushed weeks ago?

Just trying to figure this out and avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

> I guess what I'm [asking] is, if you get a conflict and resolve it after popping your stash, do you need to manually remove that stash to avoid this next time you pop with conflict?

No.  However, *this* part is correct:

> I thought stash pop was supposed to remove the stash, but I take it it doesn't if there's a conflict ...

There are a few key things to know about `git stash`, and once you know them, you may decide (as I did) to mostly *avoid* `git stash`.  The first and most important thing is this: **All `git stash push` does is make some commits.**

The commits that `git stash` (with the save or push verb) makes are on *no* branch, which is convenient in a way, but they also have some internal oddities, which makes them inconvenient: only the `git stash` command can deal correctly with these commits.  What this all means is that you're not getting anything you couldn't get by just making ordinary commits in the ordinary way.  Sometimes the special stash commits might be more convenient, and sometimes they might be less convenient.  You should know—or at least, have a strong sense about it—which of these will be the case before you run `git stash`, so that you can choose whether to use `git stash` at all.

The second thing, or group of things, to know about `git stash` is this:

- It always makes at least two commits, and sometimes three.
- The commits it makes are a bit weird.  Git will see one of them as a *merge commit* (because it technically is a merge commit), which will make the rest of Git think that it should treat that commit as if it were a normal merge (which it isn't).  That's *why* you have to deal with these commits using `git stash`.
- The stash code implements what it calls a "stash stack".  That is, `git stash push` adds a *new* stash *to* the stack, and `git stash pop` takes a stash off that stack of stashes.  If you only ever make, and then pop, a single stash, you won't see anything odd here, but if you make two or more, you'll see this "stack" behavior.
- The `git stash pop` operation is literally the same as running `git stash apply && git stash drop`.  That is, there are two parts to a pop: an "apply" step, and then—if and only if the "apply" actually *succeeds*—a "drop" step.
- The `apply` step runs a `git merge` operation.  Like any merge, this can produce *merge conflicts*.  The end result is not a new *merge commit*, though; see below.

Unlike normal commits, which live forever in your repository,<sup>1</sup> a dropped stash may be discarded permanently, and this can happen relatively quickly.  This means that if you use `git stash pop`, and Git *thinks* the stash was correctly applied, you may not ever be able to see it again—even if it *wasn't* correctly applied.  **As a result, you might want to prefer to use `git stash apply` instead of `git stash pop`.  You can then *check the application* to see if it's correct to *your* standards, rather than Git's, and only then use `git stash drop` to destroy it.**

**If the merge step that `git stash apply` runs produces merge conflicts, Git considers the `apply` to have failed.**  That is, this prevents the `git stash pop` operation from doing the `git stash drop` step.  If the merge step *does not* produce merge conflicts, Git considers the `apply` step to have succeeded, regardless of whether the merge result makes any sense.  *Carefully inspect the result of the merge* (and/or run tests on it) as Git's merge rules are purely text-based and do not *understand* files in any deeper sense.

If you do get merge conflicts, you must resolve them by hand or using `git mergetool`.  **Note that while `git reset --hard` is available, it may not bring you back the versions of files you expect.**  The merge that `git stash apply` starts uses the *current working tree* versions of the files, which may not necessarily match the *committed* versions of those files.  A normal `git merge` requires that your working tree be "clean"<sup>2</sup> before it will start, so that `git reset --hard` can undo the attempt, but `git stash` does not have this restriction.  So it's best to resolve the merge completely.  Git cannot "back it out" correctly on its own in general.<sup>3</sup>

There's a bunch more to know, but I want to keep this particular answer short (at least, short for me), so I won't go into a lot more detail, and will just list these additional bullet points:

- The two commits save the *index* state and the *working tree* state.  The index (or *staging area*) state *always* gets saved, but is then *ignored during `git stash apply` unless you also use `--index`*.  So you decide at `apply` (or `pop`) time whether to restore the saved index.
- If you use `-a` or `-u`, there's a *third* commit that saves untracked files.
- After making the two or three commits, `git stash push` normally runs `git reset --hard`, plus `git clean` if you used `-a` or `-u`.  Be sure you know what these do!  (Although the `reset` command is horribly complicated, it *is* basic Git and should be in your toolbox long before you ever think about using `git stash`.)

  The somewhat-new "partial stash" feature (`git stash push` with pathspecs, first added in Git 2.13) can't do this wholesale, so it doesn't, but there were numerous bugs in it for a while, so unless your Git version is at least 2.26 or so I don't recommend using the partial stash feature.  (I'm still not convinced the internal Git tests are adequate here, but they're way better than they were in Git 2.13.)
- The three-commit version of `git stash` has had a number of new bugs introduced recently (around Git 2.30 or so) and I'm not entirely sure they're all fixed in Git 2.35 and/or 2.36.  Because of this and of other issues with three-commit stashes, I recommend avoiding them as much as possible.
- For tough stash cases (where you've made a stash and are now unable to apply it), consider using `git stash branch` to turn the stash *into* a branch of its own.  This produces what you would have gotten had you created a new branch, committed the index if necessary, and then been ready to commit the working tree, so you can now commit the working tree and have an ordinary commit that you can use in the ordinary ways that Git handles commits.  Note that you might need to use `git stash push` to clean things up enough to use `git stash branch` at this point, though!  It's a lot easier to have made a branch and committed there earlier.

The end result of all of this is that I, at least, generally prefer to just commit something.  If it's not really "ready" to be committed, that's not a big deal: I can just reset the commit away, or I can make a new branch for the new commit.  This gets me an ordinary commit, instead of the special weird `stash@{number}` commits that require using `git stash` to deal with them.

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, forever or at least for 30 days, whichever is more appropriate.  It's relatively hard to permanently ditch a commit, but if you "abandon" one—or several—by resetting or deleting a branch name, for instance, commits that are no longer needed *do* eventually get cleaned out.

<sup>2</sup>The word "clean" here means that `git status` would say `nothing to commit, working tree clean`.  ("Clean" unfortunately does not have a single simple reliable definition in all cases, in Git.)

<sup>3</sup>If your working tree *was* "clean" at the start, Git would be able to back it out, but in this case `git reset --hard` will do the trick anyway.  If it wasn't "clean", there are some cases that Git would in theory be able to back out, and others that it would not.  There's nothing *in* Git to even try to do it, though.

Comment: There's a lot more to it than I imagined. I think from now on I'll just stage and commit my changes even if they aren't done and then do the git pull. I got away with doing stash for a while but now that I know what can happen it seems safer to just commit them and reset the commit if necessary. Thanks for the thorough answer.